# Flutter obfuscate command does not always create mapping.txt

Tags: android, flutter, mapping, obfuscation

I'm familiar with Flutter but not with Android coding.

When creating an app bundle with flutter this is what I use:

```
flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/Volumes/my_app/android_debug_info --verbose
```

The app bundle itself is fine and all working and live in Google Play store. However, what confuses me is that the `mapping.txt` does not always gets created in `path/to/app/bundle/app/outputs/mapping` directory.

Specifically after I did `flutter clean` then run the above command.
It will create the app bundle but without the mapping. But sometimes it does. But I don't know when does that happen. The [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate) actually does not help.
What am I missing here?

My `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.2 at /Users/ME/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (8 days ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
    • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
    • Dart version 2.12.1
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/ZK/Applications/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Volumes/ZK/Applications/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Facing the same issue @Zenko. Any news?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this yet.